# How to convert MS Access date to string in C#

Tags: asp.net

I was able to gather data from Access into my texboxes, but the dates won't stop giving errors. Is there a way to grab dates or is that impossible? No where on this site can I find a souluiton to convert dates to strings to display into a textbox. Any help would be great or I have to change the database dates to strings.

```
//Dates not displaying, only errors in the while loop
//strBirthday = dr["STU_BIRTHDAY"].ToString();  This won't diplay like the other 2 strings. 

protected void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\\collection\\database.accdb");
        string strQueryString = "SELECT STU_NAME, STU_ADDRESS, STU_BIRTHDATE FROM Students WHERE STU_ID = @SID";
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(strQueryString, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("SID", txtStuID.Text.Trim());
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        string strName = "";
        string strAddress = "";
        string strBirthday = "";

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            strName = dr["STU_NAME"].ToString();
            strAddress = dr["STU_ADDRESS"].ToString();
            strBirthday = dr["STU_BIRTHDAY"].ToString();   
        }
        txtStuName.Text = strName;
        txtStuAddress.Text = strAddress;
        txtStuBirthDate.Text = strBirthday;
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Get" methods of the DataReader object:

```
DateTime dt = dr.GetDateTime("STU_BIRTHDAY");
txtBirthday = dt.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Generally speaking, avoid Object.ToString().

Never store dates as strings in a database, always use the database's built-in "date" or "datetime" types. Also store date-time values as UTC, never local.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strNewDate = startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

You could use any format. In my case I have used `"yyyyMMdd"`, but there are many formats.

Answer (score 0):

look at the :-

Method 1:

```
string strQueryString = "SELECT STU_NAME, STU_ADDRESS, 
CONVERT(varchar,STU_BIRTHDATE,103) as STU_BIRTHDATE
FROM Students WHERE STU_ID = @SID";
```

Method 2:

```
string strQueryString = "SELECT STU_NAME, STU_ADDRESS, 
FORMAT(STU_BIRTHDATE, "dd/mm/yyyy") as STU_BIRTHDATE
FROM Students WHERE STU_ID = @SID";
```