# Export DATE format data from Access DB to ListView in C #

Tags: c#

help please, here is my code:

```
ListViewItem ekle = new ListViewItem();
                ekle.Text = oku["ad"].ToString();
                ekle.SubItems.Add(oku["soyad"].ToString());
                ekle.SubItems.Add(oku["dogum_tarix"].ToString());
                listView2.Items.Add(ekle);
```

With this code I get date format like this `DD/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` in `ListView` but I don't want the last
format `hh:mm:ss` to appear on the list. I tried many ways but can't figure out how to solve it. How can I get only `DD/mm/yyyy` format on list?

Comment: Have you tried providing a date format string to the ToSring() method?

Comment: I am newbie and just trying build somthing, even don't know all "key" words.

Answer (score 0):

Use the answer from this link:
[How to convert MS Access date to string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747246/how-to-convert-ms-access-date-to-string-in-c-sharp)

Here is a sample code, assuming that `oku` is your `DataReader`:

Method 1:

```
DateTime dt = oku.GetDateTime("NameOfTheColumn");
ekle.SubItems.Add(dt.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Method 2:

```
// Dont forget to include using System.Globalization;
DateTime dateValue;
dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(oku["ColumnName"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

`yyyy` is the year, `MM` is the Month, `dd` is the day.
The `/` is the separator. You can use `spaces`, `-`, or any other characters, as long as it's not on the code list of `DateTime` (see below link).

You can switch its places, depending on your preferences

Here is a link with a list of strings used to format your `DateTime`:

[C-SharpCorner.com (Date and Time)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Comment: You must first put this on your "using" lines: 

`using System.Globalization;`

And here is the link from the official Microsoft Documentation:

[Standard DateTime format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: I added another method. Both of them works for me. Try doing the Method 2. It works on SQLite, Acces DB, and MySql.